# Should it be that $\exp(\ln D)=D$?

Tags: matrices, derivatives, logarithms, operator-theory

[This article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1105.5978.pdf) gives an expression for $\ln D$:

$$\ln D=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 \psi (1) & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & \psi (2) & 0 & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & \psi (3) & 0 & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \psi (4) & 0 & . \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \psi (5) & . \\
 . & . & . & . & . & . \\
\end{array}
\right)-\ln x$$

I derived the same result using the following Mathematica code, starting from the first principles:

```
Table[DSolveValue[{f'[x] + s f[x] == x^n, f[0] == 0}, f[x], x] // FullSimplify, {n, 0, 5}]
Integrate[%, s] // FullSimplify 
Limit[%, s -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"] // FullSimplify 
Table[Coefficient[%, x, k], {k, 0, 5}] // Expand // MatrixForm
```

But when I try to exponentiate it, I do not obtain $D$. What's wrong?

Comment: You have asked three or four questions on the same topic just today. You might consider merging them rather than asking a slight modification each time you get a response.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I received useful answers, accepted some, made progress and now I am at this point.

Comment: What Mathematica code did you use to exponentiate it? It is not obvious.

Comment: @Somos Well, MatrixFunction

Comment: Check out [Higham's paper](https://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/130920137) for a detailed investigation of this phenomenon.

Comment: @greg thanks. I think, actually this definition of matrix logarithm is flawed, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4009298/different-representations-of-ln-xd-operator-which-one-is-correct